# Combine multiple cut commands into variable assignations into one cut command

Tags: bash, shell

Given a previously defined $LINE in a shell script, I do the following

```
var1=$(echo $LINE | cut -d, -f4)
var2=$(echo $LINE | cut -d, -f5)
var3=$(echo $LINE | cut -d, -f6)
```

Is there any way for me to combine it into one command, where the cut is run only once? 
Something like

```
var1,var2,var3=$(echo $LINE | cut -d, -f4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, if you're ok with arrays:

```
var= ( $(echo $LINE | cut -d, --output-delimiter=' ' -f4-6) )
```

Note that that make `var` 0-indexed.

Though it might just be quicker and easier to turn the CSV `$LINE` into something that bash parenthesis understand, and then just do `var = ( $LINE )`.

EDIT: The above will cause issues if you have spaces in your $LINE... if so, you need to be a bit more careful, and AWK might be a better choice to add quotes:

```
var= ( $( echo $LINE | awk IFS=, '{print "\"$4\" \"$5\" \"$6\""}' ) )
```

Comment: Yup just what I was looking for. Didn't know the ( $LINE ) thing changed everything to an array. Thanks.

Comment: This is a bad answer. Don't wordsplit command substitution output. Also, it won't work to begin with due to incorrect assignment syntax.

Answer (score 9):

The builtin `read` command can assign to multiple variables:

```
IFS=, read _ _ _ var1 var2 var3 _ <<< "$LINE"
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer, except that you assumed that there are only 6 fields. Maybe `read _ _ _ var1 var2 var3 _` would be more appropriate?